# Can I rewrite multiple variable assignment in a more compact way?

Tags: php, arrays, list, variable-assignment, php-5.5

I am have 11 lines of code saving various class member variables from a class into temporary variables, before using them for other things, like so:

```
// Save parts of myclass
$dutyp1 = $this->myclass->p1;
$dutyp2 = $this->myclass->p2;
...
$dutySg = $this->myclass->sg;
```

Some code that overwrites class variables happens after the above block, and then I restore variables back into the class, like so:

```
// restore parts of myclass
$this->myclass->p1 = $dutyp1;
$this->myclass->p2 = $dutyp2;
...
$this->myclass->sg = $dutySg;
```

I should note that there are other variables inside the class but only the above specific variables is what I seek to save/restore.

**Question** -- is there a more compact way to do this, instead of using up multiple variables (like `$dutyp1`, `$dutyp2`, etc), or is what I have pretty much the way to do it?  I am not looking for crazy compression/encoding, but a more compact way of doing the same thing without having to span 22 lines total for save/restore.

Comment: What was your reason/logic to have the "temporary" variables in the first place?

Comment: I'm working on a legacy codebase written by someone else and that's the code they have.  I think the logic is that the set that's being saved is the "main set of data", which gets then overwritten several times by other functions during computation of non-main data sets.  When computations are done, there was a need to guarantee that the class data remains as it was before, hence that data is restored.

Comment: "Some code that overwrites class variables ..... then I restore variables back into the class". You don't really "store" variables or data inside a class. The data (objects) are set (instantiated) to a variable or array outside the class, so that classes can be re-used for different data. If you need some data setting via a class then instantiate it to a variable, then when you need *different* data, instantiate the class to another variable. (I'm not the most knowledgeable with classes, but this sounds like it's being approached wrong)

Answer (score 2):

## 1: extract properties to (prefixed) variables

The [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function allows you to extract all properties to variables.

```
// Without prefix
extract((array) $this->myclass);
// $p1, $p2, etc

// With prefix
extract((array) $this->myclass, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'duty');
// $dutyp1, $dutyp2, etc
```

To restore the variables, you can use it’s opposite, [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php). Unfortunately, it can’t handle the prefix you used.

---

## 2: Object passed by reference

If an object is passed by reference (`&`), modifications will actually be applied to the original object.

```
$tmp = &$this->myclass;
$tmp->p1 = 123;

$this->myclass->p1; // 123
```

This way, your object is always up-to-date and you don’t have to restore.

Comment: hm that is pretty cool, didn't know that could be done, thanks!

Comment: @Dennis Slightly modified my answer in case anyone (with the same question) comes across this :)

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this:

```
//class member names
$keys = array('p1', 'p2', 'sg');

//save
$save = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) $save[$key] = $this->spec->{$key};

//restore
foreach ($keys as $key) $this->spec->{$key} = $save[$key];
```